# Dynamically update the value of variable when moving HTML slider in Angular2

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular6

Im using html round slider in my angular6 app:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

The implementation in .html file looks like this:

```
<span style="font-size: 130px;">{{sliderVal}}</span>

<input type="range" #slider min="1" max="10" value="1" class="slider" (change)="onPriceSliderChange(slider.value)">
```

The implementation of the .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample,
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss']
})
export class SampleComponent {
  public sliderVal = 1;
  constructor() { }

  onPriceSliderChange(val) {
    this.sliderVal = val;
  }

}
```

The sliderVal value changes only when the slider is moved and I un-press the mouse left button. I want to update the value of the sliderVal dynamically, every time I move the slider and not only when I un-press the mouse button. I know how to achieve this using jQuery but I don’t want to mix jQuery solution with Angular. Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding [(ngModel)] should solve your issue.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
public sliderVal = 1;
  constructor() {
   }

  onPriceSliderChange(val) {
    this.sliderVal = val;
  }

}
```

## Template

```
<span style="font-size: 130px;">{{sliderVal}}</span>

<input type="range" #slider min="1" max="10" value="1" [(ngModel)] ="sliderVal" class="slider" (change)="onPriceSliderChange(slider.value)">
```

See it in action [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). You might have to do something about the flickering though.

Comment: GENIUS. Thanks! I've added [(ngModel)]="sliderVal" and I've registered FormsModule in @NgModule({ imports: [FormsModule, ... )